# Can't Handle axios.post vuejs body data in php if statement

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

I’ve tried to send body with one parameter using `axios.post` but can’t get the body in php using `$requestBody['action']` So i’ve checked the console and network tab in chrome dev tools and found the body is correctly set like `data: "{"action":"GetOperator"}"`  but I cant handle it in a `if()` because `if()` body will not execute so i tried to check it using `var_dump()` it returns null

**Vuejs Script**

```
let actionOrder = new FormData();

                        actionOrder.append('action', 'GetOperator');

                        axios.post(BaseUrl + 'core/core.php',actionOrder)

                          .then((res) => {

                            console.log(res);

                            this.loading = false;

                          })

                          .catch((error) => {

                            console.log(error);

                          });
```

**PHP**

```
 $requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $requestBody = json_decode($requestBody, true);

    if($requestBody['action'] == 'GetOperator'){
    echo 'executed';
    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you var_dump? Did you start with what `file_get_contents('php://input')` actually returned - or did you only check after you already tried to decode that as JSON? Don’t do multiple steps in one go and then only check the final result.

Comment: @CBroe I tried to execute `if()` statement which i wasn't be able to and tried to debug it using `var_dump($requestBody['action'])` and it returns `NULL`

Comment: You are performing _multiple_ operations here, each of which can go wrong on their own (or return unexpected results.) So debug _each_ of those steps, instead of just the final result. Start with checking what reading from `php://input` actually returned - _before_ you try to decode what might already _not_ be JSON at this point, as JSON.

Comment: @CBroe `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` shows `string(0) ""`

Comment: This means that either the browser did not send any data for the file, or that the Content-Type HTTP header is wrong.

Comment: @IVOGELOV In question i mentioned that console log and Network tab in chrome dev tool shows data is correctly set i also set `application/json` header content-type in axios.post but nothing changed.I have a form which is submit successfully with all datas in my posted array data like `$requestBody['email']` and `$requestBody['pass']` but this one stucks in trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem caused because of the `core.php` which used for sending data body to file in axios.post in this line `axios.post(BaseUrl + 'core/core.php',actionOrder)` that it was included in `header.php` file so `core.php` was loaded twice in browser and data was lost.

So i moved `if()` and other operations into a separate php file which not included in header for prevent any direct accesses and the problem solved.